# htaccess from old forum url to new one

Tags: .htaccess, friendly-url

until now I have always used htaccess to rewrite URLS in order to have non-SEF url to SEF urls.

Today I am facing a new challenge that honestly, beeing non confident in regular expression, I really don't know how to achieve.

I have a situation where a forum on a website of mine has been update in the following form:

previous link: www.domain.com/forum3/topic/name-of-topic/post/7548

new link: forum.domain.com/Topic-name-of-topic/

How do I intercept /post/37764 string and tell htaccess to not consider it?

And how to instruct the server to build that kind of url instead of the provious. I am very confused about it.

Any suggestion? Thank you very much. Is there any resource that I can read to help me better understand the case?

Thanks again.

EDIT

Florian answer is correct. I just added few mods to fit it better.

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^forum3/topic/([^/]+)/post/[0-9]+$ http://forum.domanin.com/Topic-$1/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^forum3/topic/([^/]+)-[0-9]+$ http://forum.domanin.com/Topic-$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^forum3/topic/([^/]+)/post/[0-9]+$ /Topic-$1/ [L,R=301]
```

`/([^/]+)/` means that we want to catch a string containing one or more characters except `/` preceded and followed by a `/`.

This link might help you to test your `.htaccess` files :

- [Test your apache htaccess files online](http://htaccess.mwl.be/)

Comment: Thank you very much Florian. I am going to try your code as soon as i get back to my office. I will keep you informed.

Comment: It worked! I just added some string to fit it better with my cases. Please see my edited question for more details.

Comment: Hi Florian, just one question: I sometimes have links like `www.domain.com/forum3/topic/name-of-topic/post/7548`. I have tried with `RewriteRule ^forum3/topic/([^/]+)-[0-9]/post/[a-z0-9_.-]+$ http://forum.domanin.com/Topic-$1/ [L,R=301]` but with no success. Any suggestion? Thank you

Comment: Hi Aptivus, this path `/forum3/topic/name-of-topic/post/7548` should already be rewrited by the above rule (it's the same as in the question)

Comment: Sorry I pasted the wrong link. By the way I have studied the case and with some regex I have solved the issue. Thanks anyways!